# Using CORS mutliple times in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I've got a signup form that requires authentication that uses CORS go a to file that executes SQL to check a database and return if the authentication key is **valid** and **unused**.
That works, but I want to then do an additional CORS request to another file that changes the key to *used* using SQL.

The SQL is very simple and it works, my problem is that I don't know how to use CORS twice, as when I use 
    xhr.send()
it doesn't run any code beneath it in the function.

Here is the CORS function:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);

    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);

    } else {

        // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
        xhr = null;

    }
    return xhr;
}
```

And here is my function that triggers the CORS, it's an on click that runs a form:

```
$('input[type=submit]', '#orm').on('click', function() {
    let first = $('input[name="first"]', '#form').val();


    var xhr = createCORSRequest("GET", "http://myurl.co.uk/keycheck?licensekey="+ authKey +"");
    //This returns 1 if the code exists and is not set as used
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var result = xhr.responseText;
        if(result == 1){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'action': 'install',
                    'authKey': authKey
                },
                success: function(data, status){
                    //The AJAX is a database install and file download, it works, and returns success
                    if(data = 'success'){
                        var downloaded = 1;
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    //This doesn't happen, so ignore me
                }
            });
        }else if(result == 2){
            //here is where the message if your code was invalid come from
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        //This doesn't happen, so ignore me
    };
    xhr.send();
    //it works up to this point and then just stops


    if(downloaded == 1){
        var xhr = createCORSRequest("GET", "http:///myurl.co.uk/keyused.php?licensekey="+ authKey +"");

        xhr.onload = function() {
          window.location.assign('../success.php');
        };

        xhr.onerror = function() {
          // Error code goes here.
        };

        xhr.send();

    }
});
```

The CORS works once, and checks the the **keycheck.php** but not the **keyuse.php** files 
My question is how to execute CORS twice in the same function but at different intervals to each other.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll never enter `if(downloaded ==1)` because that code is executed before the first AJAX call is completed. My advice is to put the content of the `if(downloaded==1)` inside the success function on the first AJAX call

Comment: Alternatively, if you use jQuery you can use the `$.when` method. To see more about this go [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

Comment: @H.Figueiredo I tried this, but it console.logs `XHR failed loading: GET "http://myurl.co.uk/keyused.php?licensekey=1111111111111111".`

Comment: @H.Figueiredo I added a console.log in the xhr.onerror for the second CORS request and that it where is it going. The first request is still working.

Comment: @H.Figueiredo Just tried again and its also saying `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl.co.uk/keyused.php?licensekey=1111111111111111. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

There are the same headers on keycheck.php as keyuse.php

Comment: Are you sure the link you are accessing exists? (Try pasting the link you get in the error to a browser and see if you get anything) By the way, I've noticed in the second `createCORSRequest` you use an invalid http link: `http:///myurl.co.uk/keyused.php?licensekey="+ authKey +" ` (notice the 3 '/'). Don't know if you've already corrected this.

Comment: NOTICE YOUR COMMENT. You say "the same headers on keycheck.php as keyuse.php" but you are making a request on `keyused.php`. Also, the first request is not to `keycheck.php` but to `keycheck` only.

Comment: @H.Figueiredo The extra / was a typo from removing the actual address but well spotted. But your advise did help, and the address was wrong. it was keyuse.php not keyused.php. Very well noticed, I have been trying to fix this all morning and haven't!
 Thank you very very much!

Comment: No problem! :) If you need anything else, please say so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to H.Figueiredo, the problem was the placement of the second request, but also that I had a typo in the url.